# PDF from PHP is not PDF-A compatible

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, tcpdf

Via cURL I downloaded a pdf in byte form. After this I processed the cURL response

```
header('Cache-Control: private'); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $curlResponse
```

The downloaded PDF is not compatible with PDF-A standards.

Is there a way to achieve compatibility with PDF-A?

I tried searching in the documentation of FPDF and TCPDF but did not find any function for achieving this.

Comment: Do you mean `PDF/A` standard? How do you check against the standard? Which validator are you using? By the way, what is the content of `$curlResponse`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TCPDF generated PDF does not conform to PDF/A standart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997297/tcpdf-generated-pdf-does-not-conform-to-pdf-a-standart)

Comment: @Raptor Sorry, yes: PDF/A. As a validator I took [this](https://avepdf.com/pdfa-validation). This tool tells me I had six errors.

Comment: The `$curlResponse` contains the full PDF in byte form. Using the `header` lines of code I was able to transform it to a PDF file.

Comment: @Raptor I already saw this. But I did not find a way to import with TCPDF.

Comment: First of all, TCPDF is NOT a converter to PDF/A standard. If the source does not conform to the standard, the output is no way conforming to the standard.